# How can I change the order of elements printed in my twig template?

Tags: theming, 8

I have a simple twig template that looks like this:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'region',
    'region-' ~ region|clean_class,
    'row',
    '' ~ region|clean_class,
    elements.system_main ? 'controller-page',
  ]
%}

{% if content %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {% if elements.system_main %}
      {{ elements.system_main }}
      {% set elements = elements|without('system_main') %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

The main variable I am concerned with are content and elements. In the above I am trying to print elements.system_main before the rest of the content, and then remove it from the elements variable. But even though I do that it is still being printed out with the content variable.

I can't figure out why elements is being printed out at all, because the content variable only has the markup from my controller. But when I don't print the content variable it doesn't print any of the elements. How is it possible that elements.system_main can be printed out a second time after I have deleted it? I have used kint to debug the elements variable and it shows that system_main has successfully been deleted.

I am also unable to print content|without('system_main') because content is only markup.